# How to create HTTP Azure Functions that will accept multiple requests in parallel?

Tags: python, azure, http, azure-functions

I created a HTTP Azure Function for testing. This function is very simple.. It gets an string input, sends an e-mail with local time and that string name, and after that waits 25s before ending.

I ran the following code to call the function twice within an interval of 2 seconds:

```
url = "http://......"
try:
    payload1 = {"name": "Title name1"}
    r1 = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload1), timeout=2)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
    pass

try:
    payload2 = {"name": "Title name1"}
    r2 = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload2), timeout=2)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
    pass
```

I expected to receive both e-mails with a time interval of 2 seconds (Since this is the timeout interval I wait until the second HTTP CALL is placed...) However, the second call will only start after the first call is completely over, which takes 25s...

Is it right? Im using Azure Premium Plan (service app) on linux, with 1 instance. But I understood that even 1 instance is capable to run more than 100 requests at the same time..

EDIT 1:

When I increased the number of available instances the e-mails started to arrive as expected... It's no problem to increase the number of instances, however I'm not sure if I will have an increase of the costs just to make 2 instead of 1 instance available.

Thanks a lot if anyone can help me!

Answer (score -1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference#parallel-execution
[image]
This at least gives you a start for what could be causing the behavior... might try looking into automatic scale out, or if there limitations with the trigger type etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, looks like I will have to autoscale my instance... I guess azure functions handles only one request per instance..